# Find all sets in sigma algebra generated by subsets A, B

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Omega$, find all sets in $\sigma(A,B)$

There should be 16 sets. I drew Venn diagram and found these so far:

$\emptyset,A,B,A^c,B^c,\Omega,A\cup B, (A\cup B)^c,B^c\cap A, A^c\cap B, A^c\cup B, B^c \cup A$.

What are the last three?

Comment: This might be right as well (B∩A_c)∪(B_c∩A)

Comment: $A\triangle B$, its complement, and $A\cap B$ (yes, you forgot this one!)

Comment: Note that the sets you found are not necessarily distinct so that there need not be 16 sets.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you appear to understand how the generation works, here's some intuition that might help you find the remaining sets: Your Venn diagram should consist of four components, $(A \cup B)^c$, $A \setminus B$, $B \setminus A$, and $A \cap B$. The $16 = 2^4$ sets in the sigma algebra now correspond to various ways of including these four components: depending on your preference, you could think of the resulting sets as being described by 4-digit binary numbers so that $0000$ corresponds to $\emptyset$, $1111$ corresponds to $(A \cup B)^c \cup (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B) = \Omega$. The numbers in between then correspond to other unions; for instance $0101$ would be $(A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$, and $1000$ would be $(A \cup B)^c$. By mapping out this way the $13$ sets you found, you would be able to find the three missing ones.